# compile cld failed on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile [cld](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld), when I run `./configure && make` I got this error:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

And when running:

```
cd cld/ports/python
make install
```

I get:

```
sudo python -u setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'cld' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/cld -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pycldmodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycldmodule.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
pycldmodule.cc:9:57: fatal error: encodings/compact_lang_det/compact_lang_det.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autoreconf before `configure`:

```
autoreconf -vi
./configure --prefix=/usr/local #or --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: @mgilson yeah missing files should be installed too. I'm adding it to my answer along with verbose output.

Comment: For reference I first had to `sudo apt-get install automake`. Thanks guys for your help.  :)